# What / Which would you like more of?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

If you present someone with four options to choose from (and they can only choose one), should you say:

"What would you like more of?" or "Which would you like more of?"

Would the answer change if you were offering nouns (pie, coffee, etc.) or intangibles (power, speed, etc.)?

Comment: How about just: *Which one would you like?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are possible. *Which* limits the choice to just one of the options provided, while *what* doesn't limit it either to a single choice or even necessarily to those options.

But in colloquial use (at least in my British dialect) *what* is much more likely, unless you are wanting to make it clear that they may only choose one.

Comment: +1 I concur.  "Which" limits the choice, whereas "what" leaves the question open.  In my American dialect you would most likely hear "Which one" or "What one."  The usage of "one" effectively limits the context of the question to the options presented.

Answer (score -2):

Choose *what* for colloquial use, and *which* for polite use. *What* doesn't put limits, while *which* limits the choice.